# Array field in SQL BigQuery return error when to filter

Tags: google-bigquery

I have the follow query in BigQuery:

```
SELECT *
FROM `data`, UNNEST(deliveries.modalities.campaigns) as dmc
where
dmc.id = 4469
```

The struct of the field deliveries is:

```
deliveries  RECORD  REPEATED            
-----items  RECORD  REPEATED            
-----modalities RECORD  REPEATED            
----------campaigns RECORD  REPEATED            
---------------coparticipations RECORD  REPEATED            
---------------id
```

I wnat to filter deliveries.modalities.campaigns.id, but my query don't worked. Can anyone help me?

Comment: you need to flatten all arrays in the path like *UNNEST(deliveries) d, UNNEST(d.modalities) m,  UNNEST(m.campaigns) c*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach that you might try and consider is to use **CTE** as shown below:

```sql
with test_1 as (
  select *
from `your-project.your-dataset.test_deliveries`, unnest (deliveries) d
JOIN unnest (d.modalities) m
)

select *
from test_1, unnest (campaigns) c
where c.id = 4469
```

**Output:**

[image]

**My Test Schema:**

[image]

**My loaded .jsonl file to create my sample data:**

```json
{"deliveries": [{"items": [1,2,3],"modalities": [{"campaigns": [{"coparticipations": [1,2,3],"id": 1234}]}]}]}
{"deliveries": [{"items": [2,3,4],"modalities": [{"campaigns": [{"coparticipations": [4,5,6],"id": 2345}]}]}]}
{"deliveries": [{"items": [3,4,5],"modalities": [{"campaigns": [{"coparticipations": [7,8,9],"id": 4469}]}]}]}
{"deliveries": [{"items": [4,5,6],"modalities": [{"campaigns": [{"coparticipations": [10,11,12],"id": 3456}]}]}]}
```